# Arctan of Jordan Matrix

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion, jordan-normal-form

I am trying to find a formula for the arctan of a Jordan matrix. The answer would be a 2x2 matrix of lambda values.

I was thinking of using the Taylor series somehow but Im really unsure about it. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Taylor series is a good idea, but don't expand it about $0$. How should you think of your Jordan matrix?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: As usual, write your matrix $A=\lambda I + J$, where $J=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{matrix}\right]$. Expand $\arctan(x)$ in power series about $x=\lambda$. What happens when you do that and substitute $x=A$?

Answer (score 2):

It can be guessed that
$\arctan[J]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\arctan(\lambda)&\frac{1}{1+\lambda^2}\\0&\arctan(\lambda)
\end{array}\right]$,
for
$ 
J=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda&1\\0&\lambda
\end{array}\right]$ and with $|\lambda|<1$.

This is by numerical experiments.

Comment: Conjectured? :)

Comment: . . . presumably : D

Comment: I actually wasn’t sure what English word you wanted. “Conceited” is certainly not it.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Ok

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 1\\0&\lambda\end{array}\right]$$
It can be decomposed
$$ A= D+N$$
where $$ D= \left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 0\\0&\lambda\end{array}\right],\qquad  N = \left[\begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$
Let's assume that $f$ is a function that can be expanded into a Taylor series:
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$
Let us note that
$$ f'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n nx^{n-1}$$
We then define
$$ f(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n A^n$$
(assuming this series is convergent in some sense). Since matrices $D$ and $N$ commute, we can use the Newton's binomial formula to get
$$ A^n = (D+N)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\begin{array}{c}n\\k\end{array}\right) D^{n-k} N^k$$
We have $N^0 = 1$ and $N^k = 0$ for $k\ge 2$, so
$$ A^n = D^n + nD^{n-1}N$$
$$ f(A) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_n D^n + a_n n D^{n-1}N\right) = f(D) + f'(D) N$$
That is
$$ f\left(\left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 1\\0&\lambda\end{array}\right]\right) = \left[\begin{array}{cc}f(\lambda) & f'(\lambda)\\0&f(\lambda)\end{array}\right]$$
This can be used also for Jordan matrices of bigger dimension, but then we need to keep more terms in the expansion, as in bigger dimension we need a higher power $k$ so that $N^k=0$.

Comment: .  .  .  n i c e . . .